# How to increase the noise of odom topics released by gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I use turbobot3 gazebo to run the SLAM algorithm. I want to evaluate the SLAM algorithm by adding the noise of odom topic. I want to know how to add the noise of odom topic in gazebo9

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28568/how-to-increase-the-noise-of-odom-topics-released-by-gazebo?/) by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/96588/wugeshenhuaking/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Simply create a node that subscribes to you odometry topic, add noise on your data and republish them to another topic. It's up to you to choose the topics names regarding the rest of your setup.

---

Originally posted by [Bracky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28398/bracky/) with karma: 26 on 2022-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bracky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28398/bracky/) on 2022-11-21**:
You can also add it to your sensor modele e.g

0 0 -0.004645 1.5707 0 0
true



gaussian
0.0
0.1